# Deserialize a text file

Tags: java, serialization

I'm doing a small socket client/server project.

On the client side, it serializes a "city" object and saves it in a text file, then sends it to server.

On the server side, it deserializes text file and cast it back to the "city" object.

However, I got an issue on deserialization.  My server got stuck when reading that text file and it won't print out what's contained in the city object.
I wrote a sample test program to make the problem easy to understand.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class World {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("temp.txt");
      ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
      city c = (city) oin.readObject();
      System.out.println("name: " + c.getName());
      System.out.println("population: " + c.getPopulation());
      System.out.println("size: " + c.getSize());
      oin.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

My city object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class city implements Serializable {

  private String name;
  private int population;
  private float size;

  public city(String name, int population, float size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.population = population;
    this.size = size;
  }

  String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  int getPopulation() {
    return population;
  }

  float getSize() {
    return size;
  }

}
```

And my temp.txt is like this(I'm not sure why it looks different after I copy and paste):

```
 sr city鸭? p? I populationF sizeL namet Ljava/lang/String;xp ?? t a
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to deserialize the object?

Comment: Improved the grammar a bit.  Also you should include code about how you are serializing the object.  You don't have a serialVerisonUID either, which could lead to problems.  http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/